# How to setup and connect to database in .net 6 winform project?

Tags: database, winforms, .net-6.0

I'm new to Winform (.net 6), can anyone please show me a sample code on how to set up and connect to a database (SqlServer or MySQL) in Winform? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C) to a begginers guide to accessing SQL Server through C#.

The example usage to

> set up and connect to a database (SqlServer or MySQL) in Winform

I give you here:

**Form1.Designer**

```
public partial class Form1
{
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textBox_dbAddress = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.textBox_dbName = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textBox_login = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textBox_password = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();

        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(180, 88);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(132, 15);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = "Database server address";

        this.textBox_dbAddress.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(180, 106);
        this.textBox_dbAddress.Name = "textBox_dbAddress";
        this.textBox_dbAddress.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(188, 23);
        this.textBox_dbAddress.TabIndex = 1;

        this.textBox_dbName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(180, 153);
        this.textBox_dbName.Name = "textBox_dbName";
        this.textBox_dbName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(188, 23);
        this.textBox_dbName.TabIndex = 3;

        this.label2.AutoSize = true;
        this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(180, 135);
        this.label2.Name = "label2";
        this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(88, 15);
        this.label2.TabIndex = 2;
        this.label2.Text = "Database name";

        this.textBox_login.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(180, 198);
        this.textBox_login.Name = "textBox_login";
        this.textBox_login.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(188, 23);
        this.textBox_login.TabIndex = 5;

        this.label3.AutoSize = true;
        this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(180, 180);
        this.label3.Name = "label3";
        this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(37, 15);
        this.label3.TabIndex = 4;
        this.label3.Text = "Login";

        this.textBox_password.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(180, 245);
        this.textBox_password.Name = "textBox_password";
        this.textBox_password.PasswordChar = '*';
        this.textBox_password.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(188, 23);
        this.textBox_password.TabIndex = 7;

        this.label4.AutoSize = true;
        this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(180, 227);
        this.label4.Name = "label4";
        this.label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(57, 15);
        this.label4.TabIndex = 6;
        this.label4.Text = "Password";

        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(180, 286);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 8;
        this.button1.Text = "Connect";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);

        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox_password);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label4);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox_login);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox_dbName);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox_dbAddress);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private Label label1;
    private TextBox textBox_dbAddress;
    private TextBox textBox_dbName;
    private Label label2;
    private TextBox textBox_login;
    private Label label3;
    private TextBox textBox_password;
    private Label label4;
    private Button button1;
}
```

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(
            $"server={this.textBox_dbAddress.Text};" +
            $"database={this.textBox_dbName.Text}; " +
            $"user id={this.textBox_login.Text};" +
            $"password={this.textBox_password.Text};" +             
            $"Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
            $"connection timeout=30");

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Connection oppened");
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection failed");
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```